# Something is missing, not sure what

Tags: php, mysql

I have this to direct to a page after it ends inserting

```
$id = $_SESSION['hola']; 

header("location:/page/home/action.php?itemid={'"$id"'}")
```

it kept saying in error logs

> syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in

What's missing

Comment: you have an extra set of `"`s inside your string. Try with `header("location:/page/home/action.php?itemid={'". $id . "'}")` if you need to keep those braces. Otherwise simply `header("location:/page/home/action.php?itemid=$id")`

Comment: Try: `header("location:/page/home/action.php?itemid={$id}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to use here would be:

```
header("Location: /page/home/action.php?itemid={$id}");
```

Also remember the semicolon after you call the `header` function.